# Search <div> for text using, javasccript

Tags: javascript

I don't know javascript but I want to use, search on my site. I found a good example on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821938/search-div-for-text#:%7E:text=There%20you%20go.%20Used%20includes%20method%20that%20fit%20your%20needs.)
I joined all the parts and received the following code:

```js
function SearchName() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      card[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      card[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" onkeyup="SearchName();" class="form-control dsh191" type="text" placeholder="search" name="" />


<div class="d-flex m-0 p-0">
    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Abc Def</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">1234</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Qwr Tyu</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">5678</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Iop Klj</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">9000</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, but I need to search by `class = 'code'`. My question is:
How do I search for `<a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Qwr Tyu</a>` and `<p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">5678</span></p>` ? What did I try?
I duplicated javascript function code and changed the class from target to code, but nothing was received, now the search goes after the first function in the input.

- I added a new function to the input `SearchCode();`;
- In `<span>5678</span>` I added `class="code"`
- And as I said above I dubbed javascript code and I changed 2 variables: from `nodes` to `code` new class name and from `card` to `profilecard`, only the new variable but the html tag remains the same.

```js
function SearchName() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      card[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      card[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
} 

  function SearchCode() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var code = document.getElementsByClassName('code');
  var profilecard = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if (code[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      profilecard[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      profilecard[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" onkeyup="SearchName(); SearchCode();" class="form-control dsh191" type="text" placeholder="search" name="" />


<div class="d-flex m-0 p-0">
    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Abc Def</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">1234</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Qwr Tyu</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">5678</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Iop Klj</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">9000</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question: How can I search the site after 2 html tags (Search by text in tags)?

Any idea how I can change the code, or where I went wrong etc ... Thanks

Comment: try searching for <a> and then <span> they don't work together

Comment: It works for `.code` am I reading wrong when you say,*"...but I need to search by class = 'code'."*? Is the real problem is that you want to search both `.code` and `.target`?

Comment: Yes, I want to search for .code and .target

Comment: @zer00ne I write with translate if I have mistakes please correct the post for others to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one idea can be to use `innerText` on parent tag `profileCard`

```js
function SearchName() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      card[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      card[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
} 

  function SearchCode() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var code = document.getElementsByClassName('code');
  var profilecard = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

  for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if (profilecard[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter))                         {
      profilecard[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      profilecard[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" onkeyup="SearchName(); SearchCode();" class="form-control dsh191" type="text" placeholder="search" name="" />


<div class="d-flex m-0 p-0">
    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Abc Def</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">1234</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Qwr Tyu</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">5678</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#" class="dsh192 target">Iop Klj</a>
        <p class="dsh185">Code: <span class="code">9000</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```